# Django- How to test image returned in httpresponse

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http, django-views

I have a django test method that checks to see if an image returned as an httpresponse equals the image as it was opened before the http request was sent to the view:

```
def test_uploaded_file(self):
    c = Client()
    originalFilePath = '../static_cdn/test_img.jpg'
    image_data = open(originalFilePath, "rb")
    with open(originalFilePath, "rb") as fp:
        response = c.post('/', {'image': fp})
        self.assertEqual(image_data,response)
```

For some reason, the test is returning this error:

```
AssertionError: <open file u'../static_cdn/test_img.jpg', mode 'rb' at 0x7fed326b6a50> != <HttpResponse status_code=200, "image/jpg">
```

I think the issue has to do with the fact that the image returned from the view is an httpresponse and while the other image being opened in the test method is not. **Why could this test be failing? Can the image be extracted from the response?**

Answer (score -1):

You're comparing an open file to an http response. Get the image out of the http response then open it and compare.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do that, how can I get the image from the http response?